# Migrating from blogger to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogger

I'm using wordpress 4.1. All of the docs I have read about migrating from blogger to wordpress make it sound pretty easy.

> "Open your WordPress Admin Dashboard and under Tools -> Import, select the Blogger option. Authorize WordPress to access your Blogger Account, select your blogspot.com blog and within minutes, all your Blogger blog posts and comments will be available on the new WordPress site." http://www.labnol.org/internet/switch-from-blogger-to-wordpress/9707/

However, when I go to `Tools -> Import` and try to install the blogger import tool on my new wordpress site I'm presented with the following:

[image: Blogger Importer 0.7]

I can not find the FTP credentials anywhere on my blogger account, nor can I find anywhere on my blogger account where to "Authorize WordPress to access your Blogger Account". I have tried just using my regular blogger credentials to no avail. So where can I get these credentials?

Comment: This is off topic here. It's more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or the WordPress forums.

Comment: BTW: This is just WordPress trying to install the plugin that does the actual import. You are supposed to enter the FTP credentials to your WordPress installation.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - I looked for a wordpress specific stackexchange and didn't find one. You're really going to vote me down over it?

Comment: Voting to close. Should be apart of wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You should enter your FTP credentials so that WordPress can proceed on importing your blogger account. Don't you have it? Check it with your host if you don't have it.